# Get list of audio devices and webcams of the system trougth python

Tags: python, audio, video, system

Im trying to get a list of webcams and audio devices (input and output) from a linux system but I cant find anything decent out there in terms of documentation.

For video devices I know that I can subprocess a call to ls /dev/video* so in that case it may work (Even if I get no info from the device at all) but for audio devices Im kind of lost.
I would like to get a proper device list so I can show the different choices (hdmi output for example, stereo mixer, webcam mic, etc)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no rason to subprocess to `ls /dev/video*`. Just use `os.listdir` or `glob.glob`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/) which uses the PortAudio library to query your audio devices:

```
pip install sounddevice --user
python -m sounddevice
```